# Sms Receiver via BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an app which is sending and receiving SMS . sending is OK, but in receiving the SMS when application is running the receiving is OK too but when I close the app the onReceive method of my BroadcastReceiver doesn't execute , actually I am working on android 4 and I heard from a college which it could be up to android's version that means android 4 doesn't let app to receive SMS when their are not showing to user . is it right ?

here is the code which is OK (I think so)

```
 public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String ACTIVITY_SERVICE = "activity";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // something 
   }
  }
```

here is the manifest related content

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  <receiver
        android:name="com.ssol.SMSReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />               
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />` also

Comment: How do you "close the app"? "I heard from a college which it could be up to android's version that means android 4 doesn't let app to receive SMS when their are not showing to user . is it right ?" -- Android 4.4 imposes some limitations, but nothing that should impact what you are doing: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Answer (score 1):

you can receive sms and its info.

i have receive it using:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage [] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";

        if (myBundle != null)
        {
         //get message in pdus format(protocol discription unit)
            Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
            //create an array of messages
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
            {
             //Create an SmsMessage from a raw PDU. 
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                //get the originating address (sender) of this SMS message in String form or null if unavailable 
                strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                strMessage += " : ";
                //get the message body as a String, if it exists and is text based.
                strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                strMessage += "\n";
            }
            //show message in a Toast
            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

for more help you can see this post regarding sms Send and [receiving](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/receivereadsender-numbernamemessage-sms.html).

Comment: Actually the question is not about how to read SMS , the question is Why after closing the app SMMes not catching by My SMSReceiver ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your receiver in your manifest to this

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.ssol.SMSReceiver android:exported="true""
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />               
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

android:exported indicates that  the SmsReceiver class must receive event not only from the application but also from the whole Android system.

android:priority indicates the priority of your SMS receive. 1000 is the default value and seems to be the best value to use.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `android:exported` defaults to `true` once you add intent filters to a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class ReadSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages = null;

        if (myBundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            String SMS = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                SMS = messages[i].getMessageBody();4
                //SMS is the text content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works for me :)

Comment: Actually the question is not about how to read SMS , the question is Why after closing the app SMMes not catching by My SMSReceiver ?